# Returning a promise node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have a value `seed` which returns a promise which I need to pass in to the `hdkey` function which will use that output.

`seed` returns a promise and it throws an exception because i need that unwrapped response.

I'v looked at some other posts about it and I'm wondering about the fact that the value I'm trying to set (`root`), gets used for the subsequent commands.

Do I just keeping doing `.then()`?

```
var bip39 = require('bip39');
var hdkey = require('hdkey');
var createHash = require('create-hash');
//var btcLib = require('bitcoinjs-lib');
var bs58check = require('bs58check');

//const mnemonic = bip39.generateMnemonic(); //generates string
const mnemonic = "gentle mutual speak consider mandate kingdom cash explain soul exile cabin squeeze";
const seed = bip39.mnemonicToSeed(mnemonic)
                  .then(a => ); //creates seed buffer
console.log('Seed: ' + seed);
console.log('mnemonic: ' + mnemonic);

const root = hdkey.fromMasterSeed(seed);
const masterPrivateKey = root.privateKey.toString('hex');
```

Comment: `a` will be the "unwrapped" value. So put the code that needs access to that value in that function. This might help with how to think about callbacks: https://felix-kling.de/blog/2019/javascript-callbacks-misconceptions.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to await the `Promise` to get the `seed` buffer:

```js
const bip39 = require('bip39')
const hdkey = require('hdkey');

const mnemonic = "gentle mutual speak consider mandate kingdom cash explain soul exile cabin squeeze";
bip39.mnemonicToSeed(mnemonic)
  .then(seed => {
    console.log('Seed: ', seed);
    console.log('mnemonic: ', mnemonic);

    const root = hdkey.fromMasterSeed(seed);
    const masterPrivateKey = root.privateKey.toString('hex');
    console.log(masterPrivateKey);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('error to seed', err)
  })
```

Or use the `bip39.mnemonicToSeedSync` method to avoid the `Promise` interface - but with lesser performance

```js
const bip39 = require('bip39')
const hdkey = require('hdkey');

const mnemonic = "gentle mutual speak consider mandate kingdom cash explain soul exile cabin squeeze";
const seed = bip39.mnemonicToSeedSync(mnemonic)

console.log('Seed: ', seed);
console.log('mnemonic: ', mnemonic);

const root = hdkey.fromMasterSeed(seed);
const masterPrivateKey = root.privateKey.toString('hex');
console.log(masterPrivateKey);
```